# Best way to check if double equals negative infinity in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, numerical, numerical-computing

I found this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isinf but it appears to check for either positive or negative infinity.  I just want to check if a value is equal to exactly negative infinity, or in otherwords is log(0)

Thanks for answer! Based on response below, here is some code that shows what works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double c = std::log(0.0);
    auto result = c == - INFINITY;
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about `isinf` and `< 0`?

Comment: yeah, what @Quirliom said

Comment: You can check the value of infinity? *Mind blown*

Comment: @marsh infinity in the IEEE754 floating-point sense of out-of-range.

Comment: How does that differ from double.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: @marsh because it behaves like you would expect infinity to behave. For instance, a) `a/2` is still infinity if `a` was infinity, while it would be a finite number, had `a` been `MAX_VALUE` (which is finite) and b) `a/b` is `NaN` if both are infinity, while it would be `1` if both were `MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Cool! I learned something new today. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`x == -1.0 / 0.0`

This expression evaluates to true iff `x` is negative infinity.

If you are willing to include `cmath`, then `x == - INFINITY` is more readable.

Assuming that floating-point types are mapped to IEEE 754 formats, then each of them has its own infinity. `1.0 / 0.0` is a `double` infinity. It doesn't matter much the type of `INFINITY` because “usual arithmetic conversions” will take care of matching the types of the left- and right-hand-side of `==`.

Comment: if you don't want to include `<cmath>`, you can use these macros: `#define POSINF (1.0 / 0.0)`, `#define NEGINF ((-1.0) / 0.0)`, and `#define NAN (0.0 / 0.0)`. You'll probably get some warnings about overflow for constants, but they should work.

Comment: I didn't realize -Inf == -Inf, that actually looks a bit like a bug to me, but if it works, works for me!

Comment: This is platform-dependent, no?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is, but any platform that takes IEEE 754 seriously (in C++, `std::numeric_limits::is_iec559` can be used to confirm this) would work as in this answer, because IEEE 754 defines 1 / 0 as +inf, -(+inf) as -inf, and the equality x == -inf to be true iff x is -inf. The only question is whether a platform implements IEEE 754. C++ also allows extra precision for intermediate results, but inf is inf at any precision.

Comment: Yeah so you should mention that in your answer :) And the OP should check for `std::numeric_limits::is_iec559`.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't compile `1.0 / 0.0`, it complains about division by zero (at least with default settings).

Answer (score 24):

How about the obvious and explicit?

To check that a `double x` is negative infinity, check

```
x == -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()
```

If `x` is some other floating-point type, change `double` as appropriate.

`std::numeric_limits` is defined in the standard header `<limits>`. Don't forget to add it to your `#include` list.