# How to check if the 'inbuilt c++ function' log2 returns '-inf'?

Tags: c++

## The code below shows error

```
#include<bits/stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
        int n; 
        cin>>n; 
        if(log2(n)=="-inf") 
        cout<<"you entered zero"; 
}
```

## The error it shows

stack_question.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
stack_question.cpp:6:19: error: invalid operands of types ‘__gnu_cxx::__enable_if::__type {aka double}’ and ‘const char [5]’ to binary ‘operator==’
         if(log2(n)=="-inf")
            ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~

#### One more doubt

Is it a runtime error or compile time error??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Negative infinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016600/negative-infinity) or [Best way to check if double equals negative infinity in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683702/best-way-to-check-if-double-equals-negative-infinity-in-c)

Comment: You are not running the program. You are trying to compile it. It is a compile-time error. `#include<bits/stdio.h>` is just wrong. You need `#include<iostream>` for `cout` and `cin` and `#include<cmath>` for `log2`. Also note that `log2` only returns `-inf` if `n` is `+0` or `-0`, so you can just test that beforehand.

Comment: @walnut, **yes**, reading that question helped. **I got my answer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the correct code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    if(log2(n) == - INFINITY){
        cout<<"you entered is zero";
    }
}
```

The header `<cmath>` has the Positive INFINITY defined.

And the error you are getting is a compile time error as type checking is really handled by semantics analyzer.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

## Below is the code after correction

*Check line number 6 of the code*

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
        int n; 
        cin>>n; 
        if(log2(n)==-INFINITY){ 
                cout<<"you entered zero"; 
        }
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)